# added IP address to Win2k8r2, unable to use it in IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ip, iis-7.5

I've gotten another IP address from my host. I added it to the networking settings. I can now ping that new IP address. I've bound a site in IIS to that new IP address.

But i can not connect to that IP on port 80. I've tried using netstat as well as tcpview and neither one shows anything sitting on that IP/port 80. When i try to telnet to port 80, it just times out. I ruled out the windows firewall by turning it off temporarily to no effect.

I have a feeling something else is running that's using that IP on port 80, but since nothing is showing up in tcpview, maybe i am wrong.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting IIS?

Comment: Had you previously changed the IIS listening configuration away from `0.0.0.0` with the httpcfg utility?  What address is shown in `netstat` for the existing port 80 listener?

Comment: restarted both IIS and the server itself. No effect. 
httpcfg is ringing a bell - sounds like something i might have used previously. It's been a while since I've needed to ad an IP to the server .... using netsh i was able to get this to work. Thank you - i'd make yours as the answer if i could